# UPDATE Query from array values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want update values in database table by a array data on codeigniter, but i have in output error. How can fix it?

**PHP:**

```
$mainpage = $this - > input - > post('mainpage');
$data2 = array();
foreach($mainpage as $idx = > $name) {
    $data2[] = array(
        'mainpage' = > $name[0],
        'subpage' = > json_encode($this - > input - > post('subpage')[$idx]),
        'service' = > json_encode($this - > input - > post('tdadeps')[$idx]),
        'id_relation' = > $id_relation, );
    $this - > db - > where('id_relation', $id_relation);
    $data22 = $this - > db - > update('access_level', $data2);
}
```

**ERROR IN OUTPUT:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
Line Number: 612

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column '0' in 'field list'
UPDATE `access_level` SET `0` = Array WHERE `id_relation` = '2'
Filename: W:\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Comment: can you post the $main page array .........so i can write query for you because the error says there is unknown column.....

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see a bit more code, but try this code:

```
$mainpage = $this - > input - > post('mainpage');
$data2 = array();
foreach($mainpage as $idx = > $name) {
    $data2 = array(
        'mainpage' = > $name[0],
        'subpage' = > json_encode($this - > input - > post('subpage')[$idx]),
        'service' = > json_encode($this - > input - > post('tdadeps')[$idx]),
        'id_relation' = > $id_relation);
    $this - > db - > where('id_relation', $id_relation);
    $data22 = $this - > db - > update('access_level', $data2);
}
```

Let me know if worked

Comment: It does not work. A constant value in multiple row in the database was inserted.

Comment: But you got the error no more? And what are you trying to get from this code?

Comment: This code in loop (`foreach...`). inserted just last loop no all loops, ?

Comment: But you call your functions inside the loop, so